# xcode 8 shows 0% code coverage when running xctest uitests using xcodebuild

Tags: code-coverage, xcode8, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

xcode 8 shows 0 code coverage when running xctest uitests using xcodebuild, however when running from xcode the coverage details are shown.

I tried adding unittests as suggested in below stackoverflow question, however that too does not help when running the uitest's using xcodebuild

[UI Test Case not show code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718699/ui-test-case-not-show-code-coverage).

below stackoverflow question seem's to say that code coverage cannot be obtained for uitest's , but my question is how is xcode able to show the code coverage for uitest's

[Xcode 7.3.1 UITests Code Coverage always at 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38334050/xcode-7-3-1-uitests-code-coverage-always-at-0)