# UI Testing - Code Coverage for custom Framework in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have created a application and a framework. I have included the framework in the application. When I am UI Testing the application the code coverage shows only for the application code and not for the framework. Can anyone tell me how can get the code coverage for the framework?

Comment: Looks like xcode bug. Check the link https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/96314#96314

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI Test Case not show code coverage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718699/ui-test-case-not-show-code-coverage)

Comment: is there any update on this issue?